# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have shape (973, 215) but got array with shape (61, 215)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, lstm

I have received multiple diffrent `ValueErrors` when trying to solve following by changing many parameters.

It is a `time series problem`, I have data from 60 shops, 215 items, 1034 days. I have splitted 973 days for train and 61 for test.:

```
train_x = train_x.reshape((60, 973, 215))
test_x = test_x.reshape((60, 61, 215))
train_y = train_y.reshape((60, 973, 215))
test_y = test_y.reshape((60, 61, 215))
```

**My model**:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(train_x.shape[1], train_x.shape[2]), 
return_sequences='true'))
model.add(Dense(215))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics= 
['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=10,
                validation_data=(test_x, test_y), verbose=2, shuffle=False)
```

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have
>   shape (973, 215) but got array with shape (61, 215)

Comment: How can you use 2d input shape when your data is 3d?

Comment: When I do 3d shape I get ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4  I saw a suggestion of putting 2d input and then creating a batch to prevent this but didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've split your data with respect to timesteps as opposed to the samples. You need to decide on what are your samples in the first instance. For the sake of the answer I will assume these are along the first axis (assuming the data has been framed as a supervised time-series problem).

The `input_size` in LSTM expects the shape of `(timesteps, data_dim)` as explained [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/#specifying-the-input-shape), and these dimensions must remain the same for each batch. In your example, samples from training and testing have different dimensions. The batch size can differ (unless specified with `batch_size` parameter).

Your data should be split between training and testing along the first axis. Here is an analogous example from Keras tutorials:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
import numpy as np

data_dim = 16
timesteps = 8
num_classes = 10

# expected input data shape: (batch_size, timesteps, data_dim)
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True,
               input_shape=(timesteps, data_dim)))  # returns a sequence of vectors of dimension 32
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))  # returns a sequence of vectors of dimension 32
model.add(LSTM(32))  # return a single vector of dimension 32
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Generate dummy training data
x_train = np.random.random((1000, timesteps, data_dim))
y_train = np.random.random((1000, num_classes))

# Generate dummy validation data
x_val = np.random.random((100, timesteps, data_dim))
y_val = np.random.random((100, num_classes))

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=64, epochs=5,
          validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

You will notice that `timesteps` is the same for training and testing data and `x_train.shape[1] == x_val.shape[1]`. It is the number of samples that differs along the first axis `x_train.shape[0]` is `1000` and `x_val.shape[0]` is `100`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I get your point this is really helpful, I would like to ask more tho about how could I make my predictions based on the 974 days because my goal isn't to train over some shops in order to predict for the rest of them but to train on all shops for some days to test on ther rest of the days.

Comment: My data before this format were [58380 x 215] for train_x and train_y [3660 x 215] for text_x and test_y  58380 = 973 days x 60 shops and 3660 = 61 days x 60 shops so in trainx/y every 973 rows each row has info for a single day for a shop the same way for testx/y

Comment: Thanks for specifying further info!

Comment: I created my answer to address directly the error code you were given, however - if you haven't already - you need to re-frame your problem as a supervised time-series forecast.

There is a very good explanation on how to approach the problem [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-forecasting-supervised-learning/), and an example of how this can be used in LSTM [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/). Hope this helps.